# Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (Trusty Tahr) 64b - cgminer-3.7.2-x86_64-built - Error -11: Building Program - ySIZE

Tags: cgminer

firt time start mining litecoin "error -11...."
i'd like to understand more abou how to fix this..

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (Trusty Tahr)
- 64 bit notebook
- videocard: ATI Radeon™ HD 5000 Series model: 5470M
- cgminer: 3.7.2
- 3D Acelerator active
  $ glxinfo | grep render
  direct rendering: Yes
  OpenGL renderer string: AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series 
  GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
  GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render,
- cgminer:
  $./cgminer -n
  [2015-02-28 00:55:42] CL Platform 0 vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  [2015-02-28 00:55:42] CL Platform 0 name: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  [2015-02-28 00:55:42] CL Platform 0 version: OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1411.4)
  [2015-02-28 00:55:42] Platform 0 devices: 1
  [2015-02-28 00:55:42]  0   Cedar
  [2015-02-28 00:55:42] GPU 0 AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series  hardware monitoring enabled 
  [2015-02-28 00:55:42] 1 GPU devices max detected
  [2015-02-28 00:55:42] USB all: found 6 devices - listing known devices
  [2015-02-28 00:55:42] No known USB devices
  $
- mining scrypt:

  ## !/bin/sh

export DISPLAY=:0
export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1
./cgminer --scrypt --url=stratum+tcp://us2.pool.org:3333 --userpass=my.worker:1 --url=stratum+tcp://us.lite.pool.org:3333 --userpass=my.worker:1 --failover-only --shaders=80 --intensity=19

- ERROR -11 starting scrypt:
  [2015-02-28 00:51:13] Started cgminer 3.7.2
  [2015-02-28 00:51:13] Started cgminer 3.7.2
  [2015-02-28 00:51:13] Probing for an alive pool
  [2015-02-28 00:51:14] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 1024
  [2015-02-28 00:51:14] Error -11: Building Program (clBuildProgram)
  [2015-02-28 00:51:14] "/tmp/OCL2443T5.cl", line 762: warning: variable "ySIZE" was declared but never referenced

  const uint ySIZE = (1024/LOOKUP_GAP+(1024%LOOKUP_GAP>0));

"/tmp/OCL2443T5.cl", line 814: error: work group size exceeds the maximum

[2015-02-28 00:51:14] Failed to init GPU thread 0, disabling device 0
  [2015-02-28 00:51:14] Restarting the GPU from the menu will not fix this.
  [2015-02-28 00:51:14] Try restarting cgminer.
Press enter to continue:

Answer (score 0):

I see you problem within the title to your question anything x86 is 32-bit and x86 should be nowhere near anything 64-bit and of amd64 so for some reason you have the two combined also i should note that most Notebook laptops are 32-bit so simply i believe you problem lies in the lack of research done before installation of Ubuntu...

Rule #1 of computer programming- Proper preparation = positive outcome...but Improper Preparation = negative outcome.

dont worry i made a few mistakes when i first learned computer programing even deleted Windows 7 and couldn't get Ubuntu on but i learned to research before i went running and now i would consider myself a great computer programmer so sadly you might have to re install the pre-set os and then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: using 32 bit or 64 bit system and cgminer or sgminer,is it the same. i think the problem is GPU AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5470 don't support any miner.